# unable to track a variable inside a function and store them in a datastructure in java

Tags: java

Given below  is a class named Abc:

```
class Abc{

static int balance=1000;

public String method1(int amount, String password){
    String newPass=password;
    String str=newPass;
    balance=balance+amount;
    return str;
}
}
```

Above class is used in given code below:

```
class Xyz{

public static void main(String args[]){
    Abc abc=new Abc();
    int x=100;
    String y="gopal";
    String result=abc.method1(x,y);

    System.out.println("The password of the user is: "+result);
}
}
```

Now, the question is, I want to get the names of all the variables through which the value of password (i.e. y="gopal") passes away.

Is there a way to do so?

In simple words I just want to track a particular value entered by user and note the name of variables through which it passes throughout the execution.

Comment: I doubt if there's any in-built feature for that.

Comment: You mean you want to get variable names like `y, password, str and newPass`?

Comment: username @Smit exectly. you got my point .Solution?

Comment: You should use IDE like `eclipse` or `netbeans`. They provide `debugger` for such purpose.

Comment: @Gops I dont think of any solution. As  Sudhanshu said there is no built in feature for that.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to **run your program in debug mode in eclipse** and watch the values of the variables. Alternatively, you can print the values of the variables on the console and check this out. I think first approach is more efficient.